# Wordpress Database connection error while connection is successful

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I have this weird error with my wordpress website. 
Later I noticed I got an automated warning message about the plugin "Unyson", but the provided urls don't work.

When I access the main page I get this error:

[image: Database connection error]

At first I expected it to be the Database Connection settings in the wp_config.php file.

I double checked them as I tried to log in to the Admin panel. I got the error: One or more `database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.`

So I added `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` and ran the repair module. Which gave me the following result:
[image: All tables look okay]

Because after each table it says: `table is okay` I have to conclude it can actually connect to the database?

I also renamed the plugins folder _plugins and removed the unyson plugin from the folder, but the error still remains.

Does any have an idea to fix this issue?